# How to find all Javascript object methods and properties?

Tags: javascript, methods

I've found that sometimes I'll have a var with a bunch of methods and properties that I can't seem to locate somehow, event with `Object.keys` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` on both the var and the prototype.

Here's an example: I'm playing with RethinkDB and I want to override the `run` function. However, I don't know where it lives -- what object prototype I need to change, etc. In fact, I can't find any way of finding it with the functions I specified above:

```
> r.db('test').tableCreate('authors').run
[Function]
> r.db('test').tableCreate('authors')
{ [Function]
  args: 
   [ { [Function] args: [Object], optargs: {} },
     { [Function] data: 'authors' } ],
  optargs: {} }
> r.db('test').tableCreate('authors').prototype
{}
> r.db('test').tableCreate('authors').run
[Function]
> Object.keys(r.db('test').tableCreate('authors'))
[ 'args', 'optargs' ]
> typeof r.db('test').tableCreate('authors')
'function'
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames( r.db('test').tableCreate('authors') )
[ 'length',
  'name',
  'arguments',
  'caller',
  'prototype',
  'args',
  'optargs' ]
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames( r.db('test').tableCreate('authors').prototype )
[ 'constructor' ]
```

The `run` function never shows up... Any ideas?

EDIT:

I did some snooping in the source code. [this is the method I want to wrap](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/next/drivers/javascript/ast.coffee#L59).

Then, you can following the inheritance chain from TermBase to Eq ([RDBVal](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/next/drivers/javascript/ast.coffee#L121), [RDBOp](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/next/drivers/javascript/ast.coffee#L407), [Eq](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/next/drivers/javascript/ast.coffee#L581)).

`r.eq().run` returns a function -- the function I want to wrap.

@T.J. Crowder's answer: `findProps('run', r.eq())` prints out a bunch of stuff including:

```
I20150625-10:33:31.047(-7)? Props for run[[Proto]][[Proto]][[Proto]][[Proto]]
I20150625-10:33:31.047(-7)? 0: constructor
I20150625-10:33:31.047(-7)? 1: showRunWarning
I20150625-10:33:31.047(-7)? 2: run
```

So thats it!

Comment: You don't need to know who first defined it to override it, that's the beauty of inheritance. If you provide one, as the last one, it wins.

Comment: Agreed! I'd like to something like `SomeObj.prototype.run = //...`. And I have no idea what `SomeObj` is. Its returned by `tableCreate` though...

Comment: You really shouldn't modify someone else's prototype. It's generally safer to wrap the object with your own that provides the helpers, rather than touching an external object.

Comment: but then I have to have a method for all this chaining... right? As in, one method in my object for every method in the wrapped object...

Comment: `run` sounds like it should be the final link in a chain, though, so you might just be able to define a helper like `function runWithLogs(obj) { log('pre'); var r = obj.run(); log('post', r); return r; }`

Comment: Well the goal is to partially apply run with the first argument...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81563/discussion-between-chet-and-ssube).

Comment: You should check out [the JS chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys` gives you that object's *enumerable* property names. Many properties are not enumerable.

As [ssube said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056484/how-to-find-all-javascript-object-methods-and-properties/31056555#comment50134155_31056484), you don't have to know at what level a property is defined to override it. But if you want to know, you can in ES5 and later, via [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.4), which includes non-enumerable properties of an object, and [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2), which lets you traverse up the object's prototype chain.

Example:

```js
function findProps(objname, obj) {
  var p;
  
  snippet.log("Props for " + objname);
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(name, index) {
    snippet.log(index + ": " + name);
  });
  p = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  if (p != null) {
    findProps(objname + "[[Proto]]", p);
  }
}

var a = {};
Object.defineProperty(a, "foo", {      // A non-enumerable property
  value: "bar"
});

var b = Object.create(a);              // b's prototype is a
b.answer= 42;                          // An enumerable property
Object.defineProperty(a, "question", { // A non-enumerable property
  value: "Life, the Universe, and Everything"
});


var c = Object.create(b);              // c's prototype is b
c.last = "property";

findProps("c", c);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf` does yeild some new results, but I still havent found the run function!

Comment: @Chet: *"I dont actually know the object name"* Objects don't have names. Variables have names, and variables can refer to objects. Crucially, multiple variables can refer to the same object. *"I still havent found the run function"* If you're not finding `run` using `findProps` above, then the object you're using it on (or the root of the prototype chain for that object) is a *host-provide object*. They're allowed to break the JavaScript rules. Depending on *how* it's breaking them, you may not be able to wrap `run` on the object (you can pass the object into a function, though).